# Refreshing an android/res/value/ .xml with a new .xml file via a socket object through a tether

Tags: android, sockets, resources, usb, android-gridview

Two Part question:

(1) I have a few arrays that represent the state of a gridview (textArray, colorArray, etc) that I want refreshed by connecting to a server through a socket connection, downloading and replacing the old gridViewArrays.xml with a new gridViewArrays.xml located in android/res/value/ by some function call. So far I have only found that resources can not be updated on the fly but since the xml is not compiled, only parsed and pushed up in the apk, I can not see why this isn't possible. I am in the early stages of this effort but I want to be sure this is possible before I go down that path.

(2) I also would like suggestions on how to use the socket class to send and recieve information over TCP through a USB tether (cannot be wireless) to a C++ application on the other server. Any good tuts on this??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The APK is digitally signed; changing the APK by changing the resources would invalidate the digital signature.

Answer (score 1):

Resources saved under the `res/` folder are read only, you cannot alter them. Instead you should save the altered xml files to the applications local storage.

With regards to the 2nd question. There are dozens of good tutorials on how to use sockets, you'll just to have to google for them.

Comment: Only xml files under `res/raw` are copied to the device, for all other locations you cannot access files themselves but rather the arrays, views, strings, drawables, etc.. that they define.

Answer (score 0):

> but since the xml is not compiled, only parsed and pushed up in the apk

they are kind of compiled. XML resources are optimized into binary form. You can just unzip an .apk (rename to .zip) and see for yourself.

@ (1): create a file in e.g. your app directory (`getFilesDir()`) and save the updated data in there. Now instead of simply loading the values from resources check if that file exists and load data from there.

@ (2): USB tethering should be mapped to a normal network connection by the system. Any java socket tutorial should work.

Comment: Great info! Just a few questions I want to clear up. I should clarify that I want the app to have an initial gridViewArray.xml data.. before ever having to connect to the Server. Nontheless, so this is what you are suggesting: 1) make a folder outside of res titled.. "UploadXMLFolder/" 2) place a /gridViewArrays.xml file there. 3) Use getFilesDir() to find the directory holding the application files (which is where UploadXMLFolder/" will be?). 4) On "Refresh Button" click event, delete the old xml, pull the new xml through the socket, and save it to the same location 5) refresh the grid view.

Comment: you can initially load the data from resources (e.g. `res/values`) - once you have downloaded an updated version of that file (or some similar file that holds the data you want to change - doesn't need to be the same since you have to parse it anyways) you refresh what you need refreshed but use data from the file you downloaded instead. There are some limitations here because you can't use the resources directly anymore - you need some abstraction layer that handles resources <> downloaded file switching.

Comment: Perfect! I would think I could to a try (loading the downloaded file to an array) and catch (loading the res/value/ .xml to an array). I will try it and let you know how it goes. Thanks for all your help!